# Italicization of foreign common names of organisms in English texts?

Tags: formatting

I wonder when I write a formal text whether I should italicize the use of common names (not scientific names) in foreign languages.

**Example**: The leaves of the *supinosasumomo* (スピノサスモモ) are on leaf stalks 2 to 10 millimeters long, which may be slightly hairy but are usually glandless. The white flowers of the *supinosasumomo* appear in March and April - long before the leaves emerge ...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this fiction or non-fiction? In fiction, it's often recommended *not* to italicize foreign words, especially not in the "mouth" (dialog/narrative) of someone speaking two languages, since the foreign word likely isn't foreign to the speaker. In non-fiction, I'm far more uncertain...

Comment: it's non fiction. like the example above, it's an explanation article for gardening

Comment: Just to note that nearly all formatting questions are answered by style guides. If your document is for a publication, organization, company or other entity, there should be a style guide, and it should cover the formatting question. For general publication writing, use the Associated Press Stylebook (https://www.apstylebook.com/)

Comment: That's a good hint! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The convention is to italicize words in a foreign language. This includes both scientific names (since Latin is a foreign language unless your text is written in Latin) and common names in a foreign language.

Here is an example (using German):

> The sour cherry that Carl von Linné named *Prunus cerasus* is called *Sauerkirsche* in German.

Do not use italics for foreign phrases and abbreviations common in English (i.e. phrases found as main entries in *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*).

Since there are no italics in Japanese, though, **do not italicize Japanese text!**

Within Japanese text, foreign words are indicated by [katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Usage) or [romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese), emphasis is indicated through boldface or katakana.

Within non-Japanese text (e.g. when Japanese words appear in English text), set them in regular (non-oblique) type. If you need to emphasize a Japanese word within a Japanese phrase, use boldface or katakana. Book titles in the reference list are indicated by Japanese double quotation marks (『異星の客』).

If your audience does not read Japanese, consider romanizing Japanese words. Italicize these!

Comment: thanks! so in the example above I should stick to "Within non-Japanese text (e.g. when Japanese words appear in English text), set them in regular (non-oblique) type."

Comment: @TyrusRechs Yes.

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of disagreement about whether foreign words should be italicised, with numerous voices both for and against. But that doesn't seem to pertain to your case anyway.

From your excerpt, it seems you're downright borrowing a word for something that doesn't have a traditional name in English. As such, it isn't a foreign word anymore, and thus you shouldn't italicise it.

Comment: thanks, there is a traditional name in English, but the text aims at a audience that prefer the Japanese name for the plant, not the English one.